# How to substitute non-binary (other than 0/1) characters in a numeric vector with zeros (in R)?

Tags: r, replace, binary, decimal

When creating a complex funtion, I needed to convert all non-binary (other than 0/1) characters in a numeric vector to zeros:

```
cwhmisc::int(1010110.001) # 1010110; integer part; class=integer
cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001) # 0.001; fractional part; class=numeric
as.character(cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001)) # "0.00100000004749745" (unwanted nonbinaries (4,7,4,9,7,4,5) produced)
toString(cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001))     # "0.00100000004749745" (was not a solution to kill unwanted things)
nchar(cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001))        # 19 (unwanted things are really there)
as.numeric(strsplit(substr(as.character(cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001)),3,nchar(as.character(cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001)))),"")[[1]]) # 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 7 4 9 7 4 5
```

How to convert
`c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 4, 9, 7, 4, 5)`
to
`c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: `0 + (x == 1)` will do it (where `x` is your vector)

Comment: @AndrewGustar This seems to be very elegant than liuminhao's. I would just accept liuminhao's answer just for the sake of followability of the answer.

Comment: You don't actually need to split your string into characters (which your code seems to do) - `gsub("[^1]", "0", "00100456")` will give you `"00100000"`, for example

Comment: @AndrewGustar  I get your solution now: `substr( gsub("[^1]", "0", cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001)), 3, nchar(gsub("[^1]", "0", cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001)))) # [1] "00100000000000000"`. I lack of enough knowledge on `gsub`, `regex` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 4, 9, 7, 4, 5)
ifelse(x == 0 | x == 1, x, 0)
# [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
x * (x == 1)

 [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I added Andrew Gustar's solution:

```
gsub("[^1]", "0", cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001)) # "0000100000000000000"
noOfchars <- nchar(gsub("[^1]", "0", cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001))) # 19

substr( gsub("[^1]", "0", cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001)), 3, noOfchars) # [1] "00100000000000000". Remove leading "0."
```

`gsub`(pattern, replacement, string): replace all matches in pattern matching and replacement.
pattern: character string containing a regular expression (or character string for fixed = TRUE) to be matched in the given character vector.

```
"[^1]"
```

replacement: `"0"`
The character vector where matches are sought:

```
cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001) # 0.001
```

(Note: `options(digits=22); cwhmisc::frac(1010110.001) # 0.0010000000474974513` )